# Why i have an Exception in my main Class ,i think handled every exception in the program

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

For the moment i have two packages :metier and view the model package is empty.
metier contains my main app :

```
private Stage primaryStage;
private BorderPane rootLayout;

@Overrid
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
            this.primaryStage.setTitle("AddressApp");

            initRootLayout();

            showPersonOverview();
        }
```

Initializes the root layout:

```
        public void initRootLayout() {
            try {
                // Load root layout from fxml file.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("/view/RootLayout.fxml"));
                rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

Show the scene containing the root layout :

```
                Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
                primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                primaryStage.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Shows the person overview inside the root layout :

```
        public void showPersonOverview() {
            try {
                // Load person overview.
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("/view/PersonOverview.fxml"));
                AnchorPane personOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
```

Set person overview into the center of root layout:

```
                rootLayout.setCenter(personOverview);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Returns the main stage:

```
        public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
            return primaryStage;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

view contains two fxml files PersonOverView.fxml and  RootLayout.fxml all the work was with scene builder.

The entire stack trace :

```
    Executing Z:\WorkJava\BonPlansApp\dist\run139321931\BonPlanApp.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at metier.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:41)
    at metier.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application metier.MainApp
Java Result: 1
Deleting directory Z:\WorkJava\BonPlansApp\dist\run139321931
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: Executing Z:\WorkJava\BonPlansApp\dist\run2063021541\BonPlanApp.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre/bin/java
Exception in Application start method

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the entire StackTrace for the exception you're getting. That first line is almost never the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I edited my post.Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described on this line of your StackTrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
```

This is coming from the line that loads your `RootLayout.fxml` file:

```
rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
```

Basically, what that line does is tells the FXMLLoader to load the `RootLayout.fxml` file and return the root element as a `BorderPane`. You did not post your FXML file, but I suspect the first element is an `<AnchorPane...`, not a `<BorderPane...`.

Either declare the `rootLayout` in your `Main` class as an `AnchorPane` or change the FXML file's root element to a `BorderPane`.

Comment: i tried it it doesnt work .i think the problem is this : "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException": Location is not set.Do u have any idea how to set the path of an fxml file in the method getResource of the class "Class".

Comment: The `Location is not set` error was not in the stacktrace you posted. We can't really answer your question if you're providing incorrect information.

Comment: It might be a mistake happened but i re edited the stack trace now